# The object [ServiceBroker_Route] already exists in database with a different definition and will not be altered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, service-broker

I made the pre-deploy script that automatically takes the databasX service_broker_guid and put it in variable. After that I use this variable in the ROUTE DDL script:

```
CREATE ROUTE [ServiceBroker_Route]
WITH SERVICE_NAME = '//TargetDB/SourceDB/UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService',
BROKER_INSTANCE = '$(TargetDBGUID)',
ADDRESS = 'tcp://$(TargetDB_SERVER):4022';
```

However when I publish I am getting following warning:

The object [ServiceBroker_Route] already exists in database with a different definition and will not be altered.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you perform an existence check and, if it exists, issue an ALTER ROUTE command instead?

Comment: what do you mean? Put Route DDL to the pre/post deployment script?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an existence check in your pre-deployment script and, based on the result, do either a CREATE ROUTE or ALTER ROUTE statement.

```
if (not Exists(select * from sys.routes where name = 'ServiceBroker_Route'))
    CREATE ROUTE [ServiceBroker_Route]
    WITH SERVICE_NAME = '//TargetDB/SourceDB/UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService',
    BROKER_INSTANCE = '$(TargetDBGUID)',
    ADDRESS = 'tcp://$(TargetDB_SERVER):4022';
else
    ALTER ROUTE [ServiceBroker_Route]
    WITH SERVICE_NAME = '//TargetDB/SourceDB/UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService',
    BROKER_INSTANCE = '$(TargetDBGUID)',
    ADDRESS = 'tcp://$(TargetDB_SERVER):4022';
```